# What's the difference between keyword_end and end-of-input in ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

Sometimes, I ran into an error like this in ruby:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

So, I want to know the difference between `keyword_end` and `end-of-input`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`keyword_end` implies that you had a block of code with a missing `end`.

```
def fun(f)
    puts "Oops!"
```

End-of-input implies that you have already closed up blocks of code with one too many `end` keywords.

```
def fun(f)
    puts "Okay..."
end
end
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks. It is really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Keyword 'end' is the end statement in Ruby that comes at the end of methods, classes, etc. end-of-input is the actual end of your code file. The message you got means you have an extra 'end' statement somewhere.